# I cannot connect to Maria db it says socket fail all solutions I tried didn't work

Tags: java, sql, jsp, mariadb, servlet-3.0

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused

tried: adding this bind-address = ::
       tried changing from localhost too xxx.xx.xx.....

Help. thank you

Comment: Are you sure the database is up and running on that port?

Comment: yes, I am using XAMPP and I turned on the database.